# Css detect element font

Tags: css

I am using several fonts on my website , and i don't think all the fonts are loading properly . 
is there a way to check which font an element is having as style perhaps a good plug in anyone can recommend ?

I know there are plenty of debugging tools but i am searching for one that gives you all the given styles of an element not just the css code relevant to it .

Comment: Almost every modern browser has a debugging feature. Right-click on the element, and select something like *Inspect Element*. Look for computed styles.

Comment: This will tell him what the specified font is, but not the actual font being used (if the specified font is not available).

Comment: The Network panel of devtools will show you the font file downloads and you can see if they are failing.

Comment: I tried firebug for firefox , the computed section actually gives you the style the element is currently having ( independently to any font loaded or style given )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use firebug for firefox , it has a really useful way to inspect html elements ( or even scripts ) .
what you are asking for is present in the computed styling section on the right once you click on the specified element after inspecting using firebug .

you can find it at : https://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to check this, but one example is to use the developer tools in Chrome. If you view the 'Styles' applied to your text there should be a `font-family` rule.

Uncheck / check this rule to see if your text changes. If you can see no visual change on the page, then this rule is not applying any meaningful changes to your text - ie. most likely your font is not working.